# order statistic, distribution of a partial sum

Tags: probability-distributions, order-statistics

Please let me know if I can clarify my question in any way. I want to figure out the distribution of a partial sum of k largest observations in a n sample from a non-central Chi-square distribution. I have found a reference but it only considers a sample from gamma distribution. Any advice is really appreciated.

Reference:
Distribution of a sum of order statistics. Scandinavian Journal of Statistics. 1979 Jan 1:123-6.